# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to {\infty}} \frac{\int_1^x (t^2(e^{1/t}-1)-t)\,dt}{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, definite-integrals, infinity

Calculate and evaluate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to {\infty}} \frac{\int_1^x (t^2(e^{1/t}-1)-t)\,dt}{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

When plotting the upper and the lower part of the fraction separately it becomes clear that it is a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case. However, I can't solve for the integral. Also, it is not totally clear to me why the limit on the lower part approaches ${\infty}$ and not ${0}$ (considering it approaches ${{{\infty}^2}{\ln(1)}}$). Thank you a lot to everyone that can helps me with it somehow.

Comment: My professor used to say "Taylor is your friend"

Comment: With **CAS** answer is: $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Leibnitz rule maybe☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why lower part approaches zero: 
$$x^2ln(1+1/x)=\frac{ln(1+1/x)}{1/x^2}$$which is of the form $0/0$. You can use L'Hospital's Rule to show:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ln(1+1/x)}{1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{1+1/x}$$
which goes to infinity.

Now, let $$L=\lim_{x\to {\infty}} \frac{\int_1^x (t^2(e^{1/t}-1)-t)\,dt}{x^2\ln(1+1/x)}$$
Again, L is of the form $\infty/\infty$. Again, use L'Hospital's Rule:
$$L=\frac{x^2(e^{1/x}-1)-x}{2x\text{ln}(1+1/x)-\frac{1}{1+1/x}}$$
Now as mentioned in one of the comments, you can use various expansions to obtain:
$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1/2+1/3x+\cdots}{1-1/3x^2+\cdots}$$
$$L=\frac{1}{2}$$
I might have done some calculation mistake in the very last part, but I hope you know how to handle such problems now...